# What if system call number were 0 in a buffer overflow attack?

Tags: assembly, x86, system-calls, buffer-overflow, shellcode

I'm learning buffer overflow with shellcode. In a shellcode to spawn a shell by system call to execve(). Things like `mov $0x0, %eax` can be replaced by `xor %eax, %eax` to avoid NULL in shellcode. But there's a `int $0x80`. Is the number 0x80 a coincidence? What if the interrupt vector is 0x0 from the beginning date it was created? Is there a way to eliminate that NULL byte?

Comment: Your shellcode is probably writable, since that's how it normally gets injected. So you can use self modification. The `int` method is obsolete, you have `syscall` and `sysenter` which as a bonus have no zero bytes.

Comment: 32-bit Linux uses interrupt vector 0x80 for every system call.  It's an arbitrary choice but a fixed one.  You'd have no reason to ever do `int $0x0`, it would just segfault without doing anything useful. The system call number, to select whether you are invoking `read`, `write`, `fork`, etc, is passed in `%eax`, not as the interrupt vector.

Comment: Wait, are you asking what if Linux had been designed differently and used interrupt 0 instead of 0x80, and how you would write shellcode without zero bytes in that case?  Then like Jester says, you'd need to use self-modifying code.  If that's what you mean, your question would be clearer if you said "were" (subjunctive mood) in the title instead of "is" (indicative mood).  And you would mean "interrupt vector" instead of "system call number".

Comment: Thanks Nate, I've modified my question.

Answer (score 0):

**Interrupt number 0 is `#DE`, the divide exception.**  It's not really plausible that a system would be designed around using `int $0` for system calls.

OS system-call interfaces pick higher numbers because they're comfortably out of the way of x86 traps aka exceptions.  [As Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_descriptor_table#Hardware-generated_exceptions), interrupt numbers between `0` and `0x1f` are reserved for exceptions.

---

Normally Linux configured the trap gate for that IDT entry so user-space can't truly simulate a divide exception with `int $0` at all; the hardware can tell the difference between an `int` instruction vs. a `div` that faulted.  If you try that, the kernel delivers a SIGSEGV instead of a SIGFPE.

But anyway, to raise interrupt 0 without a `0` in the machine code, **`div edx` will always `#DE` fault regardless of the values in EDX:EAX**.  The quotient will always overflow if it's not a divide by zero.  (Or without any mathematical reasoning, `xor eax, eax` / `div eax` will divide by zero.)

---

Another more general way to get zeros in code (or strings along with your code) would be to use self-modifying code: normally code-injection is only possible in a page with read+write+exec permission, so either use `call` to find out EIP, or your code's location relative to a register might already be known, e.g. `xor eax, eax` / `mov [esp + 123], al` to store a zero at some location in your code.